# How to implement a Slope graph in R for two variables

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

I'm analyzing how many users have used a particular hashtag and how they have contributed to the total number of tweets. My results are:

Data:

[image]

- 20.68% of tweets related to #HashtagX are created by 20 users. Now, these 20 users only represent 0.001% of the total of 14,432 users who have ever used the hashtag #HashtagX.
- What happens if we take the top 100 users by number of tweets? 44% of tweets are created by the top 100 users.
- If we extend to the top 500 users by number of users we see that 72% of tweets is created by the top 500.

I am wondering how to implement a slope graph because I think that is a good way to show the relationship between both variables, but it is not a default graph provides for any library.

Comment: I would like to know the reason(s) because someone indicates -1 to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: Thank you @IsiahMeadows I will add my question to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows I don't know if you can advise me: I have already solved my own question, but I am wondering if I need to erase this question or improve editing in order to improve the -2 on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the ways to show the relationship between both variables ("Users" vs "Tweets") is a Slope Chart.

Visualization obtained (solved graph for the question):

[Slope Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk0jA.png)

1) Libraries

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggrepel)
theme_set(theme_classic())
```

2) Data example

```
Country = c('20 accounts', '50 accounts', '100 accounts','200    accounts','300 accounts',
        '500 accounts','1000 accounts','14.443 accounts')
January = c(0.14, 0.34, 0.69,1.38,2.07,3.46,6.92,100)
April = c(20.68, 33.61, 44.94, 57.49,64.11,72,80,100)
Tweets_N = c(26797, 43547, 58211, 74472,83052,93259,103898,129529)


a = data.frame(Country, January, April)
left_label <- paste(a$Country, paste0(a$January,"%"),sep=" | ")
right_label <- paste(paste0(round(a$April),"%"),paste0(Tweets_N," tweets"),sep=" | ")
a$color_class <- "green"
```

3) Plot

```
 p <- ggplot(a) + geom_segment(aes(x=1, xend=2, y=January, yend=April, col=color_class), size=.25, show.legend=F) + 
geom_vline(xintercept=1, linetype="dashed", size=.1) + 
geom_vline(xintercept=2, linetype="dashed", size=.1) +
 scale_color_manual(labels = c("Up", "Down"), 
                 values = c("blue", "red")) +
 labs(
  x="", y = "Percentage") +
  xlim(.5, 2.5) + ylim(0,(1.1*(max(a$January, a$April))))  # X and Y axis limits

  # Add texts
  p <- p + geom_text_repel(label=left_label, y=a$January, x=rep(1,  NROW(a)), hjust=1.1, size=3.5,direction = "y")
  p <- p + geom_text(label=right_label, y=a$April, x=rep(2, NROW(a)), hjust=-0.1, size=3.5)
 p <- p + geom_text(label="Accounts", x=1, y=1.1*(max(a$January, a$April)), hjust=1.2, size=4, check_overlap = TRUE)  # title
 p <- p + geom_text(label="Tweeets (% of Total)", x=2, y=1.1*(max(a$January, a$April)), hjust=-0.1, size=4, check_overlap = TRUE)
 # title

 # Minify theme
 p + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
      panel.grid = element_blank(),

      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,1,2), "cm"))
```